# Access Private files to only logged in users in drupal

Tags: file-permissions, drupal-8

I have a custom form with managed_file field for video upload in my custom drupal 8 module. Once video uploaded, it is accessible to everyone. I want to restrict video access to logged in users or specific user roles. I tried "Private Files Download Permission" module but it always says forbidden for everyone. I have setup private file system path and files are being uploaded on private directory but not accessible over browser. My custom form field code below: This is a field from my custom form.

```
$form['activity']['videos'] = [
    '#type'                 => 'managed_file',
    '#upload_location'      => 'private://activity/videos/',
    '#multiple'             => TRUE,
    '#description'          => t('Allowed extensions: mp4 avi'),
    '#title' => t('Upload Video'),
    '#upload_validators'    => [
      'file_validate_extensions'    => array('mp4 avi')
    ],
    '#weight' => '3',
    '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => '::fix_ajax_callback',
    ],
    '#disabled' => (!empty($activity))? TRUE : FALSE,
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following settings in [www.drupal.org/project/private_files_download_permission](http://www.drupal.org/project/private_files_download_permission):

Under "Enabled Users" and "Enabled Roles", choose who can download these files.